# Extract list from 'script type="text/json' in HTML file with Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have HTML files containing the following structures:

```
<script type="text/json" placeholder-data="1">
{"name":"john","args":{"id":989,"hobbies":["gardening","boxing","guitar","hunting"],"is_rookie":false}}
</script>
```

I am only interested in the list name 'hobbies'.
How can I extract it with Python ?

Comment: Get the text of the element with BS4, call `json.loads(text)` to parse it, then access `value['args']['hobbies']` to get that part of it

Comment: Which part of that are you unsure about? Please show your attempt so far.

Answer (score 0):

try out using the `BeautifulSoup` lib ! https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

here's a direct solution example to your issue. you will probably want to adapt it to loop over your html files and handle multiple script tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = '''
<script type="text/json" placeholder-data="1">
{"name":"john","args":{"id":989,"hobbies":["gardening","boxing","guitar","hunting"],"is_rookie":false}}
</script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')

json.loads(next(iter(next(iter(soup.find_all('script'))).contents))).get('args',{}).get('hobbies')
```

```
['gardening', 'boxing', 'guitar', 'hunting']
```

Comment: Thank you but i get 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' when i input my html file which is stored locally.  What could cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```py
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = """\
<script type="text/json" placeholder-data="1">
{"name":"john","args":{"id":989,"hobbies":["gardening","boxing","guitar","hunting"],"is_rookie":false}}
</script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("script[placeholder-data]").text)

print(*data["args"]["hobbies"], sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
gardening
boxing
guitar
hunting
```